# Pass enviromental variable on the fly to Serverless invoke local function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, shell, serverless-framework

I have the following Serverless configuration file:

```yaml
service: aws-node-scheduled-cron-project

frameworkVersion: '2 || 3'

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  region: us-west-2
  # Imports all the enviromental variables in `.env.yml` file
  environment: ${file(./env.yml)}

functions:
  ...
```

*env.yml*

```yaml
DATABASE_HOST: 127.0.0.1
DATABASE_USER: root
DATABASE_PASSWORD: your_mysql_root_password
DATABASE_TABLE: laravel
DATABASE_PORT: 3306
DATABASE_USE_SSL: false
NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_URL: http://localhost:4000
```

Now I would like to change `DATABASE_TABLE` on the fly when invoking the function locally. I have tried:

```sh
export DATABASE_TABLE=1-30-task-template-schedule && npx serverless invoke local --function notifyTodoScheduleFullDay
```

but the variable `DATABASE_TABLE` gets overwritten by the one in `env.yml`. Is it possible to do it via command line?

Answer (score 1):

On your `yml` file you can declare the table name as `${opt:tablename,'DEFAULT'}`.
This line means that you are going to give the name as a parameter from the terminal command like this `serverless deploy ... -tablename NAME_OF_THE_TABLE` if you do not give it as a parameter it takes the default name you can give it. This can generate a name on the fly.